# How to read the rest of a sequence from new line and without the space? c++

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream, removing-whitespace

So now looking at line 2, Cow- DNA Sequence; this continues on line 13 and 24 and ... I want to get this long sequence for each sequences ignoring the white space and new line in between.

This is the format of the file: [1](http://www.molecularevolution.org/resources/fileformats/phylip_dna)

This is the code, which reads the first 10 sequences only

```
ifstream file ("txt");
string line;
vector <string> vec;
stringstream s;
string name;

string strip(string & s)
{
    size_t b = s.find_first_not_of(' ');
    size_t e = s.find_last_not_of(' ');
    if (b == string::npos) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return s.substr(b, e - b + 1);
    }
}

void getSequence(){
    int i;
    int row;
    int col;
    if (file.is_open()) 
    {
        file >> row >> col;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            vec.push_back("");
        }
        i = 0;
        while (getline(file, line)) 
        {
            file >> name;
            if (line == " ") 
            {
                continue;
            }

            vec[i % row] += strip(line);
            i++;
        }
    } 
    else {
        cerr << "Error: file did not open!" << endl;
    }
    for (const string & v : vec) {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use `vector.resize(row)` instead of the loop, and `getline` does what it says, it reads a whole line.  Following that with `file >> name;` is not what you need.  I'm not sure how line 2-11 correspond to 13+ or what you're trying to do with that data.

Comment: And that goes on for how many lines? There's not enough format information to know.

Comment: See the link please. Should give you a better idea of the format. That's the file I am using. `file >> name; ` to store the name of each sequence.

Comment: You need to describe it.  The lines with a name on it is the start of a sequence I suppose.  What are the rest of the lines for?  Is the large block all one sequence?  Does each line of the large block correspond to the named lines?  Do you want line 2 + 13 + 24 + 35 + ...?

Comment: So take the second block of sequences, put it at the end of first block of sequences, third block of sequences  goes at the end of second block and soo on. I want each to merge each blocks at the end  which becomes long multiple sequence of 10 row and 705 column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help a bit.  The idea is to read the row & col then read the header line for the number of rows.  After that repeatedly read the next chunk of lines and append each to the correct item assuming the lines are interleaved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Sequence
{
    std::string name;
    std::string data;
};
using SeqVec = std::vector<Sequence>;

bool readHeader(std::ifstream& f, SeqVec& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (!(f >> v[i].name >> v[i].data))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int readChunk(std::ifstream& f, SeqVec& v)
{
    int linesRead = 0;
    std::string chunk;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(!(f >> chunk))
        {
            break;
        }
        v[i].data += chunk;
        ++linesRead;
    }
    return linesRead;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Sequence> v;

    const std::string filename = "test.txt";
    std::ifstream f(filename);
    if (!f)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int row;
    int col;
    if (f >> row >> col)
    {
        v.resize(row);
        if (!readHeader(f, v))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            int linesRead = readChunk(f, v);
            if (linesRead == 0 && v[0].data.size() == col)
            {
                //If we read nothing and the lines are the correct length we're done.
                break;
            }
            else if (linesRead < v.size())
            {
                //partial read is an error.
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& seq : v)
    {
        std::cout << seq.name << " : " << seq.data << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great help. Thank you so much. Didn't know about `struct`!

Comment: just small correction: instead && `if (linesRead == 0 && v[0].data.size() == col)`, || is needed. So `if (linesRead == 0 || v[0].data.size() == col)`. Thank you again

Comment: If that works for you, okay, but it isn't the correct condition assuming the column count is correct for the file.  It's expected that there will always be a multiple of row * lines.  The lines are read in chunks of the row count and at the end, after all of the lines have been read, it's expected that the next read will be 0 lines and that the data is the right length.  If that is not happening then your file has an incorrect column count or there's something else wrong with it.